# "Alloc magic is broken" Ubuntu 16.04, dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, ram

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 from live USB, Installation was successful. But after restarting and selecting Ubuntu option, a blank purple screen showed for a few minutes, and then I got this error

```
error:failure reading sector 0x53c49260 from 'hd1' 
alloc magic is broken at 0xc79b7400
aborted.press any key to exit.
```

What is wrong and how can I fix it?

GRUB version 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.2
Windows 8.1, Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: failure reading sector 0x53c49260 from 'hd1' indicates that  your drive is beginning to fail and you should replace it. You can run a comprehensive [SMART test](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-ssd-or-hdd-on-current-versions-of-ubuntu-1/528077#528077) to get an idea of just how bad things are but it's likely wiser to obtain a [full disk backup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc/586172#586172) before doing anything else. alloc magic is broken at 0xc79b7400 indicates a grub problem on the failing HDD.